# Application To Help Translate XSL Transformations

Tags: debugging, xslt, transformation

There must exist some application to do the following, but I am not even sure how to google for it.

The dilemma is that we have to backtrace defects and in doing so this requires to see how certain fields in the output xml have been generated by the XSL.  The hard part is spending hours in the XSL and XML trying to figure out where it was even generated. Even debugging is difficult if you are working with multiple XSL transformation and edits as you still need to find out primary keys that get in the specific scenario for that transform.

Is there some software program that could take an XSL and perhaps do one of two things:

1. Feed it an output field name and it would generate a list of all
   the possible criteria that would generate this field so you can figure out which one of a dozen in the XSL meets your criteria, **or**
2. Somehow convert the xsl into some more readable if/then type
   format (kind of like how you can use Javadoc to produce readable documentation)

Comment: The problem appears to be the developers not being well versed with xslt; and what you've is an xsl still under construction, as you're still debugging it and trying to make it work. There are a lot of standard xml development tools, I can think of oxygen, xmlspy, such tools make it easier to develop xsls but they wont generate the xsls for you to pick. I think what you're looking for is xpath expressions as you state you just need an output field. Also xslt can't be boiled down to a sequence of if-elses. Can post more details of what you're trying to do?

Comment: Hi, per question - issue is that we have to troubleshoot exceptions/defects on transactions being processed.  One step is to find out if it was caused by our system or the sender.  Sender sends one type of xml and then we convert to our internal type of xml using (mostly) xsl files.  For a system as large as ours these xsl are quite complex and can take hours to debug just to determine if the cause was bad data from the source or this was the way our xsl converted it.

Comment: You should make the output of the xslt adhere to a schema definition.

Comment: Thanks, we are using XSLT to ensure this.  In my situation we do use xslt for schema validation. The true issue lies in taking the output xml values and inserting into database, then you run into issue with unique constraint. At this point you have to determine how those unique key values were generated from the xsl to see if you generated them that way or if they were sent as those values to begin with from the source system

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say what tools you are currently using. Tools like oXygen and Stylus Studio have some quite sophisticated XSLT debugging capability. OXygen's output mapping tool (see http://www.oxygenxml.com/xml_editor/working_with_xslt_debugger.html#xsltOutputMapping) sounds very like the thing you are asking for.

Using schema-aware stylesheets can greatly ease debugging. At least in the Saxon implementation, if you declare in your stylesheet that you want the output to be valid against a particular schema, then if it isn't, Saxon will tell you what instruction in the stylesheet caused invalid output to be generated. Sometimes it will show you the error at stylesheet compile time, before you even supply a source document. This capability is greatly under-used, in my view. More details here: http://www.stylusstudio.com/schema_aware.html

Comment: Nice suggestions, +1 for those, I am using **Ultra Edit** Version 20.00.0.1054, only facility it is having is auto closing tag for any markUP opening tags.

Comment: I am currently using Stylus Studio's debugging feature.  Let me check out the oxygen tool and see what it is about.  THanks.

Answer (score 0):

It's an interesting question.  Your suggestions are also interesting but would be quite challenging to develop; I know of no COTS or FOSS solution to either, but here are some thoughts:

1. Your first possibility is essentially [data-flow analysis](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data-flow_analysis) from
   compiler design.  I know of no tools that expose this to the user,
   but you might ask XSLT processor developers if they have ever
   considered externalizing such an analysis in a manner that would be useful to XSLT
   developers.
2. Your second possibility is essentially a documentation generator
   against XSLT source.  I have actually helped to complete one for a client in
   financial services in the past (see [***Document XSLT Automatically***](http://kennethhughes.sys-con.com/node/40408)), but the solution was the property of
   the client and was never released publicly as far as I know.  It
   would be possible to recreate such a meta-transformation between
   XSLT input and HTML or Docbook output, but it's not simple to do in the
   most general case.

There's another approach that you might consider:

**Tighten up your interface definition**.  In your comment, you mention uncertainty as to whether a problem's source is bad data from the sender or a bug in the XSLT.  You would be well-served by a stricter interface definition.   You could implement this via better typing in XSD, addition of `xsd:assertion` statements if XSD 1.1 is an option, or adding a Schematron-based interface checking level, which would allow you the full power of XPath-based assertions over the input.  Having such an improved and more specific interface definition would help both you and your clients know what should and should not be sent into your systems.

Comment: Thansk, that is useful information.  In my situation we do use xslt for schema validation.  The true issue lies in taking the output xml values and inserting into database, then you run into issue with unique constraint.  At this point you have to determine how those unique key values were generated from the xsl to see if you generated them that way or if they were sent as those values to begin with from the source system.